# VMWare Unity Pause upon application close

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, suspend, pause

I am using VMWare Workstation 11 on Windows 8.1.

I have applications installed that only work on Windows 7.

I followed [this](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-02A9FC47-B544-4603-8C1C-9BAF958662C5.html) tutorial to create a shortcut on my host PC that will automatically launch the application in Unity mode.

Is it possible when I close the application to make the Virtual Machine go back to Suspend Mode (Pause)?

Answer (score 0):

I figured a way of achieving this.

Write a AutoIt or AutoHotkey script to detect when the class "**[VMWareUnityHostWndClass](http://s12.postimg.org/d8brcwujx/Untitled_1.jpg)**" no longer exists.